# Content fixed at the bottom

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, fixed

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("bottom",Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theFixed" style="position:fixed;top:250px;background-color:red">SOMETHING</div>

STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>STUFF <BR>
```

... almost works, but the height of the `theFixed` changes on scroll, how do I fix it?

Edit: maybe I wasn't clear, I don't need the content to be fixed at the bottom of the 'window' or the outer container, I could use CSS for that.

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS to affix it to the bottom? EDIT: This is what I did with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/916/

Comment: What is this script for?? See this without script http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/915/

Comment: To make it work properly remove this script.

Comment: Is this what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/917/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the desired height explicitly using CSS `height` property:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#theFixed").css("bottom", Math.max(0, 250 - $(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

```css
#theFixed {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theFixed" style="position:fixed;top:250px;background-color:red">SOMETHING</div>

STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>STUFF
<BR>
```

Also, not related to your problem, but as general advice: when you register an event listener for events such `scroll`, `resize` etc. you usually want also to *debounce* the event handler execution, so that the UI remains responsive to others kind of event.

More about [event debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).